# Angular 9 set priority level for HTTP requests

Tags: angular, angular9

Are there any ways to set the priority level for angular HTTP requests, when sending multiple requests concurrently.

What I am trying to achieve is, when I send a set of HTTP requests to process concurrently, then in the middle if I send a new request. I want that new request to precede in the order and to be the next request to process.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe look into [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap), that cancels previous observables when a new one comes in.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't want to cancel the request, but to de-prioritize it

Comment: Then you could think about some kind of LIFO queue structure, but note you don't have fine control over the browser running requests in parallel (typically ~5).

Comment: there is no default api that allows that. i would advice not to try to implement it as the overall performance would be decresed

Comment: https://medium.com/cloud-solutions-international/how-to-group-http-requests-into-a-queue-with-angular-interceptor-9aedd5560697

Comment: There is nothing out of the box that HTTP provider, you will have to implement custom solution